# How to create a live gps tracker using Folium in PyQt5 Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, gps, folium

I am working on a project where I have a `gpx` file which contains the `latitude` and `longitude`.

I need to draw a line in a `pyqt5` window in a real-time, which means, it should load the window and then keep on drawing the line.
This will later be replaced with live gps data from a vehicle so that we can plot where the vehicle is moving.

As of now, using `folium` and `gpxpy` I have been able to plot the line, but I am unable to find any useful resource which explains how you can do that in real-time.

Below is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import folium
import gpxpy

class MapWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MapWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Parse the GPX file
        gpx_file = open('Init.gpx', 'r')
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)

        # Create a Folium map object
        m = folium.Map(location=[51.44948037, -0.47322678], zoom_start=25)

        # Add the GPX track to the map
        for track in gpx.tracks:
            for segment in track.segments:
                folium.PolyLine([(p.latitude, p.longitude) for p in segment.points], color='red', weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(m)

        # Create a QWebEngineView object to display the map
        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        self.webview.setHtml(m._repr_html_())

        # Create a layout and add the webview to it
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.webview)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MapWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output;

[image]

Can anyone recommend a possible implementation which would allow live data refresh?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to draw a line in a pyqt5 window in a realtime, which means, it should load the window and then keep on drawing the line

In [PyQt](https://doc.qt.io/qt.html#qtforpython), that would require a [`QtCore/QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QTimer.html), as illustrated in "[`QTimer` example for PyQt5](https://pythonpyqt.com/qtimer/)":

> If an operation is performed periodically in the application, such as periodically detecting the CPU value of the host, then the QTimer timer is needed.
>
> When the window’s control receives a Timeout signal, it stops this timer.

In your original codes, lines were drawn with `folium.PolyLine...add_to(m)`.

Instead, you could start with an empty polyline:

```
self.polyline = folium.PolyLine([], color='red', weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(self.m)
```

And then loop with `QTimer` to add lines from the GPX data (or eventually the live GPS data)

```py
# Create a QTimer object to update the polyline periodically
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.add_point_to_polyline)
        self.timer.start(1000)  # Update every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
```

The `add_point_to_polyline` methods would draw lines by updating the locations attribute of the `folium.PolyLine` object, which is stored as `self.polyline`.

```py
    def add_point_to_polyline(self):
        try:
            point = next(self.points_iterator)
            self.polyline_points.append(point)
            self.polyline.locations = self.polyline_points
            self.webview.setHtml(self.m._repr_html_())
        except StopIteration:
            self.timer.stop()
```

Putting it all together:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import folium
import gpxpy

class MapWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MapWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Parse the GPX file
        gpx_file = open('Init.gpx', 'r')
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)
        
        self.points_iterator = iter([(p.latitude, p.longitude) for track in gpx.tracks for segment in track.segments for p in segment.points])
        self.polyline_points = []

        # Create a Folium map object
        self.m = folium.Map(location=[51.44948037, -0.47322678], zoom_start=25)

        # Add an empty polyline to the map
        self.polyline = folium.PolyLine([], color='red', weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(self.m)

        # Create a QWebEngineView object to display the map
        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        self.webview.setHtml(self.m._repr_html_())

        # Create a layout and add the webview to it
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.webview)

        # Create a QTimer object to update the polyline periodically
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.add_point_to_polyline)
        self.timer.start(1000)  # Update every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)

    def add_point_to_polyline(self):
        try:
            point = next(self.points_iterator)
            self.polyline_points.append(point)
            self.polyline.locations = self.polyline_points
            self.webview.setHtml(self.m._repr_html_())
        except StopIteration:
            self.timer.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MapWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```